# How do I run keepass2?

Tags: mono, keepass

I'd like to run KeePass2 on Ubuntu 10.04 - how do I do that?

Comment: Might I suggest using keepassX? It's available in the repositories and I haven't found anything wrong with it yet (been using it for years now).

Comment: @iamatrain and others: KeePassX didn't support the newer kdbx-database format (password history, multiple attachments, custom entries with [protected in-memory streams](http://keepass.info/features.html) e.g. storing recovery passwords safely and a lot more features), the latest version of KeePassX (2.0) finally released this month supports the newer format and is a complete rewrite. There are no PPAs yet from developers/maintainers/contributors, but it's easy and quick to build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

*10.04 - lucid*

I've been running Keepass2 on Lucid using the standard mono in the repositories (mono -V = *mono JIT compiler version 2.4.4*)

Note - from the [keepass website](http://keepass.info/download.html) this is an "unsupported" configuration... however, I'm happy with that since I've never had any issues running this configuration and it means I dont need that one extra PPA that could make my system "unstable" :)

**to install**

Download the portable KeePass package (v2.19 at the time of writing this).  This is a zip package which should open in *Archive Manager*.  Extract the contents into its own folder - for example `~/Downloads/keepass`

Install the mono windows forms:

```
sudo apt-get install libmono-winforms2.0-cil mono-devel
```

Finally, lets create a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Run *System - Preferences - Keyboard Shortcuts*

Add a new shortcuts with the command:

```
bash -c "cd ~/Downloads/keepass; mono KeePass.exe"
```

Bind that to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

*To install on 11.04 and above*

It is available in the repositories, you can install it. It is the keepass2 package.

## [keepass2](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/keepass2) [image: Install keepass2]

Comment: I can't find anything related stating that this is an unsupported configuration, but there is a section about [Mono](http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html#mono) and various distributions or platforms now. I also found  a [Keebuntu](https://github.com/dlech/Keebuntu) repository that I wanted to mention here.

Comment: I had to install `mono-complete` to get it to work together with KeePassRPC ...

Answer (score 2):

**For Ubuntu 12.04 and above**

The latest KeePass version is available through this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jtaylor/+archive/ubuntu/keepass) (as of today *2.30*) :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jtaylor/keepass
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install keepass2
```

[image: keepass screenshot]