# Sync KeePassX with KeePass2

Tags: security, password, keepass

Simply put:
In Ubuntu I am using KeePassX and in Windows KeePass2. In am not able to export/import passwords from one to another.

I would prefer to use the same database, but I don't really know how.

If there is no possibility to sync the 2, can you recommend another password vault, which is able to sync passwords from 2 OS, using a shared DB.

Thanks

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Win 7.

Edit:

I have noticed that KeePass2 is available in the Software Center, so I have installed it, and I can successfully open my Win7 database. Now I will migrate my KeePassX passwords. I am seeing now a huge difference in the looks. While KeePassX doesn't exactly have Ubuntu like look&feel, it's 100 times more elegant than the interface KeePass2 comes with. Well, maybe that was my initial decision for installing KeePassX on my Ubuntu machine. I can't remember.

@fossfreedom, please add your comment as a response, so that I can accept it.

Thank for the suggestion

Comment: interesting question - however, for myself I use keepass2 in both windows and ubuntu running with mono... have you considered that?

Comment: I haven't considered that option, because for some reason, when I installed keepass on Ubuntu I ended up with keepassX. Didn't bother, and just got used to it. I am seeing now in the Software Center that KeePass2 is there, plus I found the .deb installer on SourceForge. So I am investigating it now. Probably it's the best solution to have KeePass2 on both OS. I think you can add your comment as a response :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### an alternative...

When dealing with critical data such as passwords I personally prefer keeping the same software and database rather than depending upon some-sort of sync or export/import process.

Fortunately, keepass2 runs very well via Mono - so if you are one of the rare breed who is prepared to host Mono libraries on your computer, then you can install Keepass2 via the Software Center.

#### [keepass2](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/keepass2) [image: Install keepass2]

This will install all the relevant parts of Mono needed to run Keepass2

[image]

---

Linked Question:

- [How do I run keepass2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76868/how-do-i-run-keepass2?rq=1)

Comment: Why not use KeePassX on both systems? Their website has a Windows version: https://www.keepassx.org/downloads/